# iOS Static library private methods and properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I want to create a static library. I have a class for example `Class_A`. It's a public class. So I add `Class_A.h` to `Public Headers` section. But `Class_A` has some internal methods and properties that I use inside library and I want hide them for public using. Is it possible some how to hide private methods properties and variables from public using (I don't want that another developers see them. For example how UIKit classes does this), and unhide for internal using?

Comment: You can create "Class_A_Private.h" and have class extension there, and inside have your private members and methods.

Comment: Could you write an example how it will look like. As I understand. I create `Class_A.h` (add to public headers) and `Class_A_Private.h` (add to private headers). As I understand I will use in my library `Class_A_Private.h`, but developers outside will use `Class_A.h`. Ok, but how interface should looks like. Should `Class_A_Private.h` duplicate public part of `Class_A.h` and so on?

Comment: just do not declare your methods  in .h file. Other classes cannot access these methods. You declare only public methods in .h file.

Comment: Ok, but how I will have internal access from classes that I use in my library to the private methods that I don't declare in .h file? They will not see them. Methods and properties should be private outside the library and public inside.

Comment: you can use performSelector() as you know your private methods.

Comment: @tyt_g207: performSelector is not the good way, it won't give you compile time errors and very hard to maintain and debug the code. Please see answer below.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's not perfect. However, I don't know how 2 classes A & B in the library can access to each other. Because, rowwingman want that the class A can be access from inside of library. And he want just to hide these methods outside of library.

Comment: It seem that with Extensions, classes inside library can access to 'extended' methods from other classes? It's good to know that. Edit: I see your "import" section. You are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Private Extension in Private Header file "Class_A_Private.h" (you can name the private header whatever you want).

```
#import "Class_A.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - Class Extension

@interface Class_A ()

// Some properties and methods here.

@end
```

Now import your private extension in "Class_A.m" and other source files as:

```
#import "Class_A_Private.h"
```

Make sure you do not include "Class_A_Private.h" in list of public headers and mark them as private headers instead.

Reference: **Use Class Extensions to Hide Private Information**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW6